# marker wont show on google map

Tags: javascript, maps

I was able to put markers on the map, but since I'm using GMap2 I cant put markers on the map anymore. I want to use GMap2 so I can make lat lng out of an address.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyDrwris-0kRdY16oIQoGc_1qsdOgHbJrXo"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("chart"));
    map.setUIToDefault();

   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
   var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);
   map.setCenter(pos, 14);

   //until now it works fine, but when I add a marker it does nothing

 var marker = new GMarker({
    position: new GLatLng(52.15664,5.40567),
    map: map,
    title: 'NAME'
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried map.addOverlay(marker)? You may also want to check that your marker's coordinates are within the visible map - you can use map.getBounds() to determine this.

Comment: addOverlay seems to work but now its static in the left upper corner even when I zoom in/out.
getBounds doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: getBounds won't do anything itself.  You need to do something with the result of getBounds (e.g. console.log it out) and see whether your marker's coordinates are even within those bounds.

Comment: oke I give (52.15664,5.40567) as position
when I consolelog getBounds it I get a few things
ya -> hd -> lo=0.037582529303198206, hi=0.15090536000824994
za -> ld -> lo=0.887457646892784, hi=0.9325150008337899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

Firstly, you're including two versions of the mapping API, one of which has escaped parameters for some reason. This may be because it was copied from somewhere else. If you require the V2 API, you only need to include that one. Be aware that the API is due to be retired by Google next year.

Also, your marker instantiation code is incorrect. You should pass the latlng position as the first parameter, then the options as the second in object literal format, e.g.:

```
var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(<coord>, <coord>), { title:"My Title" });
```

Finally, you aren't adding the marker itself to the map. You use the `addOverlay` method to to this.

Here's a worked solution. Press the 'Add Marker' button to add a marker in a random position to the map:

```
<html>
<head><title>Map Test</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map;
function initmap() {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("chart")); 
    map.setUIToDefault(); 

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                         position.coords.longitude); 
        map.setCenter(pos, 14); 
    });
}

function AddMarker() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    var point = new GLatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), 
                            southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point, { title:"My Marker" }));
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initmap()">
    <div style="width:300px;height:300px" id="chart"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="AddMarker();" value="Add Marker"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the above assumes that geolocation works. In a real world application, you should be testing for errors as illustrated by the API documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: thanks! I only changed this "map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point, { title:"My Marker" }));" and now it completely works :)